# multiple equations alignment

Tags: equations, align, alignment

I want to write three equations in the \begin{align}\end{align}

```
\begin{aligned}
\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}} &f_i(x), & \qquad \left(i=1,\,2,\,\,\dots,\,M\right),\\
\text{sujeita a } &\phi_j(x)=0,&  \left(i=1,\,2,\,\,\dots,\,J\right),\\
&\psi_k(x)\leq 0,  & \left(i=1,\,2,\,\,\dots,\,K\right),
\end{aligned}
\end{align}
```

This is my output:
[image]

But I want that $f_i(x)$ be left aligned with $\phi_j(x)=0,$ and $\psi_k(x)\leq 0,$
Any suggestion?
I will be very greatful.

Thank in advance

Comment: I don't think `\min` and `f_i(x)` should be aligned separately.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. All of you helped me a lot. I'm very grateful!

Answer (score 3):

You appear to have cropped out the equation number align would have provided - if you are looking for just one equation number, you can uncomment the commented lines here and comment out the alignat ones - or you can have the three equation numbers with alignat.
(The excessive spacing in the code is for readability purposes here - no need for it in your actual document)

The extra braces around the min are to show it aligned with the text below - again, for illustrative purposes - I'd be inclined to agree with hesham that this may not be the best alignment for this display.

I have left the \left( and \right) on the first line to highlight the undesirable effect they have on the spacing. Please avoid them if possible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
%\begin{align}
%\begin{aligned}
\begin{alignat}{3}
&{\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}}} &\quad &f_i(x),          &\quad &\left(i=1,\,2,\,\,\dots,\,M\right),
\\
&\text{sujeita a }       &\quad &\phi_j(x)=0,     &\quad &(i=1,\,2,\,\,\dots,\,J),
\\
&                        &      &\psi_k(x)\leq 0, &\quad &(i=1,\,2,\,\,\dots,\,K),
\end{alignat}
%\end{aligned}
%\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: Alignat example]

Comment: Excuse me. What package do you have used, starting from `\documentclass{..}`?

Comment: Apologies - homebrewed documentclass - replaced now. Thanks.

Comment: No apologies :-)...don't worry.

Answer (score 2):

The tool of choise to have full control on the alignment columns spacing is `alignat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{3}
 &\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}}&&f_i(x), & (i & =1,2,\ldots, M),\\
 &\text{sujeita a }&&\phi_j(x)=0, & (j & =1,2,\ldots, J), \\
&&\quad&\psi_k(x)\leq 0, &\qquad (k & =1,2,\ldots K), 
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My preference would go to `alignedat`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
&\!\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}} 
  &\quad& f_i(x),          &\qquad& (i=1,2,\dots,M),\\
&\text{sujeita a} 
  &\quad& \phi_j(x)=0,     &\qquad& (i=1,2,\dots,J),\\
&
  &\quad& \psi_k(x)\leq 0, &\qquad& (i=1,2,\dots,K),
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
&\!\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f_i(x),
  &\quad&                  &\qquad& (i=1,2,\dots,M),\\
&\text{sujeita a} 
  &\quad& \phi_j(x)=0,     &\qquad& (i=1,2,\dots,J),\\
&
  &\quad& \psi_k(x)\leq 0, &\qquad& (i=1,2,\dots,K),
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

In the second display, the objective function is not aligned with the bounds, which is more usual, I believe.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Something of similar using `flalign`? I will use an `array` or `alignat` enviroments.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
 &\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}}&&f_i(x),\quad  (i=1,2,\ldots, M),&&\notag\\
 &\text{sujeita a }&&\phi_j(x)=0,\quad    (i=1,2,\ldots, J),&&\\
&&&\psi_k(x)\leq 0, \quad (i=1,2,\ldots K),&&\notag
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `alignat` enviroment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
&\!\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}} &\quad& f_i(x), \quad  (i=1,2,\ldots, M),\\
&\text{sujeita a }& & \phi_j(x)=0, \quad (i=1,2,\ldots, J),\\
& & & \psi_k(x)\leq 0, \quad (i=1,2,\ldots K),
\end{alignat*}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you used `alignedat` within `equation`, you wouldn't need `\notag`.  Also, on the first line, the last element should be aligned with the similar elements in the other two lines.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Approved! 

Answer (score 1):

In OpTeX, the classical `\eqalign` macro is impoved. It has unlimited columns (like `\matrix`) with alignment `rlc rlc ...` The `c` column puts `\eqspace` (it means the space between equation systems) and you can set the value of it to the required size.

```
$$\eqspace=1em \eqalign{
   &\min_{x\in {\bbchar R}} &&& f_i(x),          &&& (i=1,2,\dots,M),\cr
   &\hbox{sujeita a }       &&& \phi_j(x)=0,     &&& (i=1,2,\dots,J),\cr
   &                        &&& \psi_k(x)\leq 0, &&& (i=1,2,\dots,K),
}
$$

\bye
```